# What is the best way to search in multiple fields in django?

Tags: python, django

I have the following model in my `models.py`, and I want to search based on its three fields.

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=128, null=False, blank=False, unique=True)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=128, null=False, blank=False)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
    lastname = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
    parent = models.ForeignKey('self', null=True, blank=True, related_name='children', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

There are also three separate inputs for entering the text, one for `name`, one for `last name`, and one for `username`. The user should at least fill in one input, or if the input string was a part of main string, the main string should be returned.

[image]
This is my API, but it does not return anything, and the result list is always empty.

```
def search_users(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        try:
            to_be_searched_username = request.GET.get("username", None)
            to_be_searched_name = request.GET.get("name", None)
            to_be_searched_lastname = request.GET.get("lastname", None)

            supervisor_username = request.headers['Authorization']
            supervisor = Profile.objects.get(username=supervisor_username)
            if not((to_be_searched_name or to_be_searched_lastname) or to_be_searched_username):
                return Response({"message": "Enter a search term"}, status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)
            else:
                results = supervisor.children.filter(
                    username__icontains=to_be_searched_username and to_be_searched_username is not None
                ).filter(
                    name__icontains=to_be_searched_name and to_be_searched_name is not None
                ).filter(
                    lastname__icontains=to_be_searched_lastname and to_be_searched_lastname is not None
                )
            return Response({'results': results}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
        except:
            return Response({"message": "خطا در دریافت اطلاعات"}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

I will be grateful for any help or advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter with:

```
def search_users(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        to_be_searched_username = request.GET.get('username')
        to_be_searched_name = request.GET.get('name')
        to_be_searched_lastname = request.GET.get('lastname')

        supervisor_username = request.headers['Authorization']
        supervisor = get_object_or_404(Profile, username=supervisor_username)
        if not (
            to_be_searched_name
            or to_be_searched_lastname
            or to_be_searched_username
        ):
            return Response(
                {"message": "Enter a search term"},
                status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT,
            )
        else:
            results = supervisor.children.all()
            if to_be_searched_username:
                results = results.filter(
                    username__icontains=to_be_searched_username
                )
            if to_be_searched_name:
                results = results.filter(name__icontains=to_be_searched_name)
            if to_be_searched_lastname:
                result = result.filter(
                    lastname__icontains=to_be_searched_lastname
                )
        return Response({'results': results}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```